# How To Make iPhone6 Plus Landscape Mode Work Better with Bootstrap3?

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, twitter-bootstrap-3, landscape

I noticed an odd problem with iPhone6 Plus in Landscape Mode and Bootstrap3 with its media queries. Basically, there's almost enough space on the iPhone6 plus in Landscape Mode to make it act like a tablet iPad in Portrait Mode.

The iPhone6 Plus Landscape Mode has a pixel width of 736px.
The iPad Portrait Mode has a pixel width of 768px.

When trying to do grid styling with Bootstrap3, the col-sm-* works only for 750px and up. So, you can capture the iPad Portrait Mode and make it work well with that class. However, it doesn't work well with iPhone6 Plus Landscape Mode.

How can I override Bootstrap 3 so that col-sm-* CSS class works for 736px and up, fixing both container and container-fluid width and column width? The end goal would be to allow iPhone6 Plus Landscape Mode to act more like the iPad Portrait Mode.

Comment: I tried to fix this more elegantly by generating a [custom bootstrap template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072323/how-to-make-iphone6-plus-landscape-mode-work-better-with-bootstrap3) with SM at 730px but this did not work, but below targeted media query is still a way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone can come up with a better answer, what I'm having to do is create a media query just for the iPhone6 Plus in Landscape Mode, and fix issues.

```
/* iPhone6 Plus Landscape Mode Fixes */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* FIXES GO HERE */
}
```

A more desirable answer would be to adjust .container, .container-fluid, and .col-sm-*, perhaps.